# Gstreamer multiplex raw audio and video for H264streaming

Tags: embedded, gstreamer

I have an embedded device running Linux.  It has an image sensor and a microphone and I'm using GStreamer to process that input data.  The following works to convert the video to H.264, the audio to AAC, and save the results in an MP4 file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src \
    ! video/x-raw,width=2560,height=720,framerate=30/1,format=GRAY8 \
    ! queue \
    ! videocrop right=1280 \
    ! videoconvert \
    ! vpuenc_h264 \
    ! h264parse \
    ! mpegtsmux name=mux \
    ! filesink location=/run/media/mmcblk2p4/test.mp4 sync=false async=false \
      alsasrc device=\"hw:0,0\" \
    ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=22050,channels=1 \
    ! queue \
    ! audioconvert \
    ! avenc_aac \
    ! mux.
```

The native video from the hardware is double-wide 720p (2560x720), which I'm cropping to 1280x720.  `vpuenc_h264` is a hardware H.264 encoder for my SoC.

But I want to be able to stream the multiplexed audio and video.

I can successfully stream just the video this way:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src \
    ! video/x-raw,width=2560,height=720,framerate=30/1,format=GRAY8 \
    ! videocrop left=0 right=1280 \
    ! videoconvert \
    ! vpuenc_h264 \
    ! h264parse \
    ! rtph264pay \
    ! udpsink host=192.168.5.2 port=5000 sync=false async=false
```

Does anyone know a good way to stream the multiplexed audio and video?

The `mpegtsmux` is incompatible with `rtph264pay`.  This is not surprising.  But I am not familiar with the myriad of GST plugins that I might be able to use instead.  Is there a different mux that is compatible with `rtph264pay`?

Also, is there any way to mux audio and video in a way that the result can both be streamed and saved to a file (e.g. using a `tee` element)?  I think it would be pretty wasteful if I need to perform two different muxes, although I'll definitely do that if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the result from `mpegtsmux` via UDP directly. No need to wrap it into RTP. But if you wanted to wrap it into RTP you should use `rtpmp2tpay`.